# Self Sizing UITableViewCells with UITextViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, autolayout, size-classes

I am using sizing classes to make two separate layouts for a UITableViewCell.  I am using IB to create all of the constraints.  I have four UILabels and one UITextView in the cell.  The wAny, hAny class works perfectly.

The hCompact, wRegular class was getting a broken vertical constraint, which I fixed by giving the vertical spacing constraint from the UITextView to the content view a 999 priority instead of 1000.

An issue still exists that causes the UITextView to collapse all the way (or the cell to be sized such that it covers the UITextView completely) when the cells are first presented.  All out-of-view cells render fine when they come into view, and the original cells also render appropriately when they come back into view after going out of view.

I want to be able to use self-sizing cells and have the UITextView render correctly upon load.  It would also be nice to know why I had to set the priority of the constraint to 999 to fix that layout warning at run-time.

This is only occurring on my hCompact, wRegular class which, in my opinion, has a less vertically complex set of constraints set up than the other sizing class.  I have included an image of the UITextView selected and showing the constraints on the right.  I gave the UITextView a lime background for debugging.  As you can see, it looks rather odd in IB.  I will provide any other info as requested.

[image]

Comment: There is not a constraint set up for the height of the UITextView.  I wouldn't think I'd need one.  It's just not laying out the frames correctly when it immediately loads up.